# point of instantiation and name binding

Tags: c++, instantiation, name-binding

I am confused about the point of instantiation with the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int){std::cout<<"int"<<std::endl;}//3

template <typename T>
void g(T t)
{
    f(t);//4
}

void f(double){std::cout<<"double"<<std::endl;}

int main()
{
    g<int>(1);//1.point of instantiation for g<int>
    g<double>(1.1);//2.point of instantiation for g<double>, so f(double) is visible from here?
    return 0;
}
```

I though f is a dependent name and 1. is the point of instantiation for g< int > and 2. is the point of instantiation for g< double >, so f(double) is visible for g(1.1), however the output is

```
int
int
```

and if I comment the declaration of f(int) at 3, gcc reports an error (not surprise) and points out f(t) at 4 is the point of instantiation(surprised!!).

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void g(T) [with T = int]’:
test.cpp:16:10:   required from here
test.cpp:9:5: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope, and no    declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
  f(t);
     ^
```

Can anyone clear the concept of point of instantiation and name binding for me please?

Comment: Only ADL is performed from the POI (and it won't find the second `f` for fundamental types, which have no associated namespaces). The non-ADL part of unqualified lookup is performed from the point of definition.

Comment: Moving the definition of `f(double)` prior to the definition of your `g` method does seem to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, but my point is ADL should be able to find `f(double)` even if it appears after the definition of `g`. 0x499602D2's explain seems to be right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`f(t)` is a dependent unqualified function call expression, so only functions found within the definition context and those found via ADL are candidates. `f(int)` is visible within the definition context, but not `f(double)`, so overload resolution resolves to `f(int)` for both calls.

`f(double)` cannot be found by ADL because built-in types have no associated classes or namespaces. If you passed in an argument of class type, and there was an overload of `f` taking this type, ADL will be able to find it. For example:

```c++
void f(int);

template <typename T>
void g(T t)
{
    f(t);
}

class A {};
void f(double);
void f(A);

int main()
{
    g(1);   // calls f(int)
    g(1.1); // calls f(int)
    g(A{}); // calls f(A)
}
```

`f(A)` is called because it is located in the global namespace, and `A`'s associated namespace set is the global namespace.

Comment: put `class A {};` in front of `void f(A);` then everything works fine, thanks.