# Point of instantiation clarification

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

Consider the following code, taken from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/name_binding.htm:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(double) { cout << "Function f(double)" << endl; }

template <class A> struct container{ // point of definition of container
   void member1(){
      // This call is not template dependent, 
      // because it does not make any use of a template parameter.
      // The name is resolved at the point of definition, so f(int) is not visible.
      f(1); 
   }
   void member2(A arg);
};

void f(int) { cout << "Function f(int)" << endl; }

void h(double) { cout << "Function h(double)" << endl; }

template <class A> void container<A>::member2(A arg){ 
   // This call is template dependent, so qualified name lookup only finds
   // names visible at the point of instantiation.
   ::h(arg);  
}

template struct container<int>; // point of instantiation of container<int>

void h(int) { cout << "Function h(int)" << endl; }

int main(void){   
   container<int> test;   
   test.member1();
   test.member2(10);
   return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Function f(double)
Function h(double)
```

I understand this, but what I don't understand, when the article states

> The point of instantiation of a template is located immediately before
>   the declaration that encloses its use. In this example, the point of
>   instantiation of container is the location of the explicit
>   instantiation

...is why when I move the definition of `void h(int)` **above** what is labelled as the point of instantiation, `h(int)` still **does not** get called.  It only gets called when I move it **above the definition of the function** `void container<A>::member2(A)`.

This is the case in VS2017 and g++, so clearly either the article is badly worded or I am missing something.  Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514337/point-of-instantiation-and-name-binding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [point of instantiation and name binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514337/point-of-instantiation-and-name-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the link posted above ([point of instantiation and name binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30514337/point-of-instantiation-and-name-binding)) ultimately does answer this question, however it is not as clear as it could be.  I have found [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20170223135332/http://codeidol.com/community/cpp/the-c-instantiation-model/21722/) and [this page](https://abseil.io/tips/49) which further aided in my understanding, hence I post them here so others can benefit.